# ./zshrc config, doing a function to do git add, git commit -m "message" and git push

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to do a function in my ~/.zshrc file, to do a git combo. I Know if you use a "$1" it should receive a parameter, when i use the alias like "function_name var" and the $1 it's replaced with the var but it keeps returning a error message saying that git commit isn't receiving a message "Abort commit due to empty commit message".

```
function gall () {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$1"
    git push
}
```

Comment: Are you providing a commit message when you *call* the function? `gall "This is a commit"`, not just `gall`.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that part

Comment: Are you sure? `git commit -m ""` is what produces the error message you are seeing.

Comment: How, *exactly*, are you calling `gall`?

Comment: gall "commit message", that why i'm finding strange it doesnt work :(

Comment: What does `type -f gall` show?

Comment: You mention an alias: you don't have some other alias involved, do you? (Functions and aliases are two different things.)

Answer (score 1):

First here is an alternative I can suggest you with the explaination of the code:

```
gitall() {
    git add *
    git commit -m "$([ "$1" != "" ] && echo "$1" || echo "update")"
    git push
}
```

`$1` is the first parameter, so this means this is the string you'll pass to `git commit -m` :
`$([ "$1" != "" ] && echo "$1" || echo "update")`
Which means :

```
if [ "$1" != "" ]
then
    git commit -m "$1"
else
    git commit -m update
fi
```

Another important thing is to run this command `source ~/.zshrc` or to re-open the terminal to reload the changes you made

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version for other's reference:

#command for git commit

```
function gcommit() {
  readonly commit_msg=${1:?"The commit message must be specified."}
  git add .
  git commit -am "${commit_msg}"

  if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    git push origin "$2"
  fi
}
```

example:

- gcommit "feat: feature" feat/feature-branch
- if second argument exists then it commits and pushed to the branch